# Server.MapPath inside Application_End handler in Global.asax

Tags: asp.net, global-asax, application-end

I want to save a file when my application ends.

For that, I need to get the root folder of the application.

The only way I know to do that is using `Server.MapPath("~")`, but this does not work, even through `HttpContext.Current.Server` because there is not current context, as far as I understand.

Is there a smart & simple way to get that folder path?
Will I have permission problems, trying to create a file in the root folder?

Any alternative ideas how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use `HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath`, which will always work.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Request.MapPath("")
> 2. Request.PhysicalApplicationPath
> 3. HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath

**Edit**

It should be `HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath` only as the other two option will be null in Application_End handler.

Comment: It is there. I am using VS 2010. Web Application. In Global.asax.cs file under `Application_End` handler, you can type the above mentioned code...Right ?

Comment: Yes, but it will be `null`.  This is why he's asking the question in the first place.

Comment: +1. Thanks. You are right. I actually could not figure out how to fire the Application_End event initially.